# Another way to say "before" or "in advance"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

I am writing a (computer science) paper and want to express the sentence "A acquires the lock before B acquires it." in a more complex way.

Can I say:

"A acquires the lock antecedent to B."

or can I use "precedently" or "precedingly"? I found these words on Google but I couldn't find example sentences of how to use these words.

Comment: Please explain “more complex”.  What do you mean by it? And why do you think your paper would be better because of it?

Comment: I want to use a more difficult word that has a clearer and specific meaning. "Before" has various meanings

Comment: Which specific meaning are you intending? Which meaning of *before* do you wish to avoid.

Comment: @Jim OP has a good point.

Comment: @Kris -  I guess I’m missing it then

Comment: @Kris  Hmm,  ok is this sentence intended to establish a priority relationship or to describe the chronological relationship between two events?  If the latter then A takes(or has) priority over B with respect to lock L

Comment: If you are saying that the time at which A acquires the lock is earlier than the time at which B acquires the lock, then what possible ambiguity can the use of "before" have? Any decent editor would throw "antecedent to" back into your face asking you what on earth you meant. KISS.

Comment: When you say you want to describe something in a “more complex way”, it comes across as seeking non-functional obfuscation. Try asking for something “more precise” instead, and explain (in your question) what ambiguity you are concerned about with “before”.

Answer (score 2):

"A acquires the lock **prior** to B."